# Accessing Amazon Production Info AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I need a simple way to get general product information from Amazon into an object in my rails application. I would like to be able to search Amazon product info and return title, author, page count and cover photo for each search result.

I have found information about using AWS to do this but none of the examples provide a detailed way to do so. Seems like it should not be that heard. I am a newbie for rails.

Answer (score 0):

This [amazon-ecs gem](http://www.pluitsolutions.com/projects/amazon-ecs) allows you to access Amazon product information using Ruby. The developer's page provides plenty of usage examples.

Installation:

```
$ gem install amazon-ec
```